# How to change multiple text box value from a specific button of each with same same class name in java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create an E-commerce cart where quantity increase or decrease with button, since cart have multiple items so multiple text box and button have same class name. For testing purpose I created 5 text boxes with buttons, one to increment and another one to decrease. When I click any button they only change

```js
var dec = document.getElementsByClassName("dec_button");
var inc = document.getElementsByClassName("inc_button");
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("num");

for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  dec[i].addEventListener("click", Dec);
  inc[i].addEventListener("click", Inc);

  function Dec() {
    x[i].value -= 1;
  }

  function Inc() {
    x[i].value = +x[i].value + 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="dec_button" value="-">
<input type="text" value="0" class="num">
<input type="button" class="inc_button" value="+">
<br>
<hr>
<input type="button" class="dec_button" value="-">
<input type="text" value="0" class="num">
<input type="button" class="inc_button" value="+">
<br>
<hr>
<input type="button" class="dec_button" value="-">
<input type="text" value="0" class="num">
<input type="button" class="inc_button" value="+">
<br>
<hr>
<input type="button" class="dec_button" value="-">
<input type="text" value="0" class="num">
<input type="button" class="inc_button" value="+">
<br>
<hr>
<input type="button" class="dec_button" value="-">
<input type="text" value="0" class="num">
<input type="button" class="inc_button" value="+">
<br>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accessing the elements by index in the loop, which can lead to closure issues, traverse the DOM in each click event to find the related `input` whose value should be changed. Try this:

```js
var dec = document.getElementsByClassName("dec_button");
var inc = document.getElementsByClassName("inc_button");
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("num");

for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
  dec[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.value = parseInt(this.nextElementSibling.value, 10) - 1;
  });
  inc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.previousElementSibling.value = parseInt(this.previousElementSibling.value, 10) + 1;
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="dec_button" value="-">
<input type="text" value="0" class="num">
<input type="button" class="inc_button" value="+">
<br>
<hr>
<input type="button" class="dec_button" value="-">
<input type="text" value="0" class="num">
<input type="button" class="inc_button" value="+">
<br>
<hr>
```

Here's the same thing in jQuery:

```js
$('.dec_button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().val((i, v) => parseInt(v, 10) - 1)
});

$('.inc_button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).prev().val((i, v) => parseInt(v, 10) + 1)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="dec_button" value="-">
<input type="text" value="0" class="num">
<input type="button" class="inc_button" value="+">
<br>
<hr>
<input type="button" class="dec_button" value="-">
<input type="text" value="0" class="num">
<input type="button" class="inc_button" value="+">
<br>
<hr>
```

Comment: Hello Rory McCrossan...How to Get the value of test box. if I want to alert this value

Comment: You're already getting the value. Its either `this.nextElementSibling.value` or `this.previousElementSibling.value`, depending on which button was clicked

Comment: and How to get value of text in JQuery?

Comment: `$(this).prev().val()` or `$(this).next().val()`